# Python's CSV module writes header in first row instead of the column names

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to write dict to csv file. I add specific column names, but, they writes in the first row, not in the header (tried to open via Libre Office)
Here is the code:

```
    def write_csv():
        with open(f'RTD {1}.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, delimiter=',', fieldnames=['one', 'two', 'three'])
            writer.writeheader() 
            writer.writerow({'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3})
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: That looks completely correct, the header will be in the first line in the csv file...

Comment: You cannot rename the header in a LibreOffic/Google Sheets/Excel sheet. They're given to help find coordinates and change them, so they're not really headers but rather a tool used to locate cells.

Comment: Either you write the header to the first row - as its now done, or you dont have a header at all. Code works as it should. Because CSV does not have any formatting rules, once you open the CSV in in excel or Libre Office, you have to add the formattign yourself..

Answer (score 0):

your code works just fine. csv files consider first row as header.

i believe your problem is spread sheets like libreoffice not displaying header in a different format and letting you filter and .etc which is totally normal for these softwares. because they provide you a tool (most of time in home tab) to add filters as you see fit.

[image]